# Using MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP with SQL Server status, statusText and responseHeader are all null

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, msxml6

We've been using MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP for a long time with SQL Server.

Recently it just stopped working properly.

When we execute the following code we no longer receive the status, statusText and responseHeader.

Here's some sample code:

```
DECLARE @ret INT,
    @postData NVARCHAR(4000) = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><note><to>Bob</to><from>Betty</from><heading>Reminder</heading><body>Hello There</body></note>',
    @status NVARCHAR(32) ,
    @statusText NVARCHAR(32) ,
    @responseText NVARCHAR(MAX) ,
    @responseHeader VARCHAR(2000)


    DECLARE @token INT;
    EXEC @ret = sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP', @token OUT;
    IF @ret <> 0 RAISERROR('Unable to open HTTP connection.', 10, 1);

    DECLARE @url VARCHAR(255) = 'https://www.ibm.com' -- JUST DID THIS CAUSE IT WAS THE FIRST DOMAIN I THOUGHT OF

    EXEC @ret = sp_OAMethod @token, 'open', NULL, 'POST', @url, 'false';

    EXEC sp_OAMethod @token, 'setRequestHeader', NULL, 'Content-type', 'text/xml'
    EXEC sp_OAMethod @token, 'setRequestHeader', NULL, 'Accept', 'text/xml'
    EXEC sp_OAMethod @token, 'setRequestHeader', NULL, 'Accept-language', 'en-CA'

    EXEC @ret = sp_OAMethod @token, 'send', NULL, @postData;
    IF @ret <> 0
        BEGIN
            EXEC sp_OAGetProperty @token, 'status', @status;
            SELECT 'error' response, @status status
            EXEC @ret = sp_OADestroy @token;
            RETURN;
        END
    EXEC sp_OAGetProperty @token, 'readyState', @status;
    EXEC sp_OAGetProperty @token, 'status', @status;
    EXEC sp_OAGetProperty @token, 'statusText', @statusText;
    EXEC sp_OAMethod @token, 'getAllResponseHeaders', @responseHeader;

    DECLARE @responseTable TABLE (response VARCHAR(MAX))
    INSERT INTO @responseTable (response)
    EXEC sp_OAGetProperty @token, 'responseText'
    SELECT TOP 1 @responseText=response FROM @responseTable


    EXEC @ret = sp_OADestroy @token;
    IF @ret <> 0 RAISERROR('Unable to close HTTP connection.', 10, 1);  
    SELECT  
        @status status, 
        @statusText statusText, 
        @responseText responseText, 
        @responseHeader responseHeader
```

Just execute the code, the response table should have the Status, StatusText and ResponseHeader values, but it doesn't, for me.

Comment: Umm, you're supposed to use OUTPUT parameters when calling sp_OAGetProperty, otherwise not much will happen

Comment: Sorry, i had a RETURN at the endo of this line in my original post:

IF @ret <> 0 RAISERROR('Unable to close HTTP connection.', 10, 1);  RETURN;

That was left inadvertantly.

Comment: It doesn't. I just realized that i had left the return in and didn't want anyone to have to figure that out.

Answer (score 0):

Stupid me forgot the OUT at the end of the property call.

Thanks to siggemannen.